# What does overlaying parameter of layout.axis object of plotly mean?

Tags: python, plotly

I tried to understand what this actually mean but couldn't go so far.

I play with the code below to understand it. If I delete all the overlaying parameters only the 4th will appear. If I delete one of them then only that axis is visible. I can not make any statement out of this behaviour. And no,

> If set a same-letter axis id, this axis is overlaid on top of the corresponding same-letter axis, with traces and axes visible for both axes. If "False", this axis does not overlay any same-letter axes. In this case, for axes with overlapping domains only the highest-numbered axis will be visible.

the documentation also doesn't say much to me. Can anybody decrypt this explanation? Thanks.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6],
    name="yaxis1 data"
))


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[40, 50, 60],
    name="yaxis2 data",
    yaxis="y2"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[4, 5, 6],
    y=[40000, 50000, 60000],
    name="yaxis3 data",
    yaxis="y3"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[5, 6, 7],
    y=[400000, 500000, 600000],
    name="yaxis4 data",
    yaxis="y4"
))


# Create axis objects
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        domain=[0.3, 0.7]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="yaxis title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#1f77b4"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#1f77b4"
        )
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title="yaxis2 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#ff7f0e"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#ff7f0e"
        ),
        anchor="free",
        overlaying="y",
        side="left",
        position=0.15
    ),
    yaxis3=dict(
        title="yaxis3 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#d62728"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#d62728"
        ),
        anchor="x",
        overlaying="y",
        side="right"
    ),
    yaxis4=dict(
        title="yaxis4 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#9467bd"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#9467bd"
        ),
        anchor="free",
        overlaying="y",
        side="right",
        position=0.85
    )
)

# Update layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="multiple y-axes example",
    width=800,
)

fig.show()
```

Here is the demonstration of the result when I delete all of the "overlaying" parameters.
[image: example result when the overlaying parameters are deleted]
One more thing to note, I've seen multiple scatter traces being in the same plot and no mention of overlay there. I know this is related to axes but maybe I miss some fundamental knowledge about what is happening when there are multiple axes and maybe even meaning of overlaying of axes? What does it even mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the way (I think) it works. When you create a second axis (e.g. a second y-axis), you basically create a new sub-plot that is rendered *in the same place* as the subplot with the first y-axis.

As a result, only the second (or last) subplot is visible. In your case, it means that when you remove the `overlaying` argument, you only see the last scatter - the one that is attached to y-axis #4. But - that's not what you typically want. In most cases, you'd like all the scatters, from all the overlapping subplots, to be visible at one. That's why you specify the `overlaying=` argument. It tells plotly not to 'hide' the lower sub-plots, but rather to make all the sub-plots except the bottom one "transparent" - as a result, all the subplots are overlayed, and visible.

Hope this helps.

There's a long discussion about the meaning of overlay [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3074).

BTW - one may ask why not make everything overlayed, always. There's a use-case for non-overlay too:

[image]

Comment: This was the intuitional answer I was looking for!